# how to redirect to signin page in react if JWT token is incorrect

Tags: reactjs, authentication, local-storage, jwt

I am storing JWT token in localstorage.

Currently if I delete the token form localstorage and refresh the browser the user gets back to the signin screen.
But if I again put random value as JWT token manually in localstorage and from URL if I change path to the dashboard page, It pushes to the dashboard page but data doesn't shows up which is ideal because the token is random eg. 12345 or soo.

But user can still see the static website structure.
How to should I redirect to signin page if token is randomly set ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you might check if the api request fails for any reason from token side, which will return the status code of 401 user unauthorized, then return user to the sign in page.

basically there are two conditions you might return user to the sign in page(it can be even more based on your logic and some special condition), one when there are no token and and also when api returns 401 status code!

Comment: I got ur point, but. In my condition I am changing URL nd by doing that my API is not getting called as My API will get called only on Sign-in button click

Comment: yes sure, i mean when you call the dashboard api request with out any token or wrong JWT token ( your case ) you might get status code of 401 ( b/c your user has the wrong token ), and based on that you might redirect user to the sign in page!, redirect does not matter!

Comment: `{status: "error", message: "Invalid Token..."}
message: "Invalid Token..."
status: "error"` I guess I can use this.

Answer (score 1):

You should have an endpoint in your backend where to send the token you get from localStorage and before loading the Dashboard, validate that the response that your backend returns to you has a status 200 and not a status 401

Comment: In network tab I am getting  this

`{status: "error", message: "Invalid Token..."}
message: "Invalid Token..."
status: "error"`